# Minimum prerequisites to stay camping on private land (finca) in Spain (Canary Islands)?

Tags: legal, children, spain, camping

What are the minimum prerequisites if you want to stay camping on private ground in Spain (especially on the Canary Islands)? I do have the owner’s permission.

I mean by law: Are there any restrictions, especially if you want to stay some weeks camping with your children on private land (finca) without any building for holiday?

Do no need to build a toilet? Do you need a drinking water connection or is it enough to have your drinking water from bottles?

Comment: I have the owner’s permission. EU regulations? Are they important? Spanish law is the only thing that is relevant in this case, I think.

Comment: Spain is part of the EU, so EU regulations apply here.

Comment: I have edited my answer adding Canary Isles specific information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend on where in Spain, as that is regulated by local government (autonomías). You should ask the local municipality (ayuntamiento) for an authorization, and you will probably be required to pay some form of tax.

I've been trying to find an authoritative source but, as Spanish government is so decentralised, regulation is so fragmented that I couldn't find any.

**Edit after clarifications**

Regarding the Canary Islands. Autonomic regulations in the Canary Islands can be found [here](http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/libroazul/pdf/17172.pdf). The link is a bit old and in spanish, but I could not find anything newer. From what I could gather elsewere, it is still current.

The relevant part is article 6

> Artículo 6. En cualquier caso, cuando se trate de acampadas en montes
>   de particulares, el propietario de los mismos o aquellos que deseen
>   acampar con permiso de la propiedad, deberán solicitarlo a la
>   Viceconsejería de Medio Ambiente con una antelación de diez días.

Which means that if you want to camp in a private property, the campers or the land owner must request an authorization to the environment administration at least 10 days in advance.

[Contact information (in Spanish)](http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/estorg/ver-unidad-organica.jsp?id=24855)

Comment: Good to know. Does it say anywhere if the camper is limited to a maximum number of days? Not needed for the answer, just curious. In the UK it's two nights for example.

Comment: @GayotFow There are limits when using public designated camping areas (7 days) or when sleeping en-route (24 hours). Nothing is mentioned when camping in a private land.